# javascript simple count in object?

Tags: javascript, object, count, iteration

Sorry I'm a new student, sorry this is so simple yet I still do not understand the object even after some research.

```
var obj = [
    {day:"monday", status:"present" , reason:""},
    {day:"tuesday", status:"present" , reason:""},
    {day:"wednesday", status:"absence" , reason:"sick"},

  ]
```

to be like this :

```
Total days: 3 
Total present: 2 
Total absence: 1
```

do i have to use iteration ?

```
for (var key in obj) {
    var currentObj = obj[key];
}
var totaldays = obj.length ;
console.log(totaldays);
```

and why  `var totaldays = obj.length ;` didnt work without iteration ?

also #2 question

```
{day:"monday", status:"present" , reason:""},
```

and

```
{"day":"monday", "status":"present" , "reason":""},
```

are those same or not ? sorry i feel like more understand with questioning in person/community rather than read in w3school or another cause I've tried over and over again and still get confused.
but I always read first, asking is my last option

Comment: That is Array of Object

Comment: #1 `var totaldays = obj.length;` should work and for #2 read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 3):

**Q1, Count**

You could use an object with the status as key and count up.

```js
var obj = [{ day: "monday", status: "present", reason: "" }, { day: "tuesday", status: "present", reason: "" }, { day: "wednesday", status: "absence", reason: "sick" }],
    count= { days: 0 };

obj.forEach(function (o) {
    count[o.status] = (count[o.status] || 0) + 1;
    count.days++;
});
   
console.log(count);
```

**Q2, [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)**

```
{ day: "monday", status: "present", reason: "" }
```

and

```
{ "day": "monday", "status": "present", "reason": ""}
```

are basically the same. If the identifier is like a valid variable name, you could omit the quotes.

Comment: also add `days` in count object

Answer (score 1):

## question 1:

`var totaldays = obj.length ;`

didn't work without iteration ?,
Because i think the object `obj` is not get executed correctly, if the object is executed by the compiler correctly you will get the length.

Try this sample fiddler. https://jsfiddle.net/1sb9r9uc/

## question 2:

Those are basically the same. If the identifier is like a valid variable name, you can eliminate the "".

Answer (score 0):

i made a small fiddle

```
var obj = [
    {day:"monday", status:"present" , reason:""},
    {day:"tuesday", status:"present" , reason:""},
    {day:"wednesday", status:"absence" , reason:"sick"},

  ]
  var tdays=0;
  var pr=0;
  var ab=0;
  tdays=obj.length;
  for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
  {
  if(obj[i].status=='present')
    pr++;

   if(obj[i].status=='absence')
   ab++;
  }

  console.log('Total days:'+tdays)
  console.log('Present: '+pr)
  console.log('Absence:'+ab)
```

This might be helpful
     https://jsfiddle.net/ubq4058s/

Answer (score 0):

Think obj.length can work well, don't know why it doesn't work for an array.

For the question#2, they should be same, I usually don't use string as object property name just like `{a:100}` not `{"a":100}`

The following code work pretty well and think it's easy to understand

```
var obj = [
    {day:"monday", status:"present" , reason:""},
    {day:"tuesday", status:"present" , reason:""},
    {day:"wednesday", status:"absence" , reason:"sick"}
  ];

var present=0,absence=0;

obj.forEach(function(v){
    if(v.status=="present") present+=1;
    if(v.status=="absence") absence+=1;
});

console.log("total days",obj.length);
console.log("total present",present);
console.log("total absence",absence);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can count your items like that:

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

Comment: This will not help.